# Google Chrome not showing 1 specific page

Tags: google-chrome

A friend has a laptop and every time he tries going onto a page (asda groceries if anyone is curious) - if he is lucky it loads the logo and the black background of the nav bar, but that's it but most of the time chrome throws the ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED and refuses to load the page at all.

At one time, he managed to get it working by using system restore and then downloading chrome again but that worked twice for maybe 2 days and then he was back to this again.

Changed his dns settings in windows to opendns and Google dns which worked for 1 day, then back to this again.
When he boots into safe mode with networking, it works fine.
I have tried a lot of tuts suggesting fixes but none have worked.

His phone, my iPhone, my S7 and my laptop all open the page fine, so it is something on his laptop. He has scanned for viruses/etc and is very aware and careful of what he downloads. I have looked through the running processes & services and there doesn't look like there's anything bad there.

Since it works in boot mode, there has to be something, but I am not sure where to go now.

Any suggestions as to what to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something on that Browser's cache (Chrome maybe) it's generating that behaviour.
And even if you restore that machine again with system restore, you are restoring the cache for the browser also. Even if that restore is at an earlier point in time, but the browser cache existed then also. 
And the cache is remaining even after you uninstall / install Chrome.
Only if you create the user session from scratch or create an new user session. 
Otherwise I think only a clean install on that laptop will solve your problem.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I have cleared the cache and any/all browser history/passwords/cache/etc several time and it did nothing so yeah, looks like its a full install. Thanks